# Compressing data shared between rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

We have a database table that tracks changes to long strings for auditing purposes. This data compresses very well with something like bzip because the rows share a lot of text. The data does not compress very well when compressing the table with MySQL, and I assume this is because the compression used by MySQL condenses repeated content in a single row only.

Is there a way to transparently compress row information in MySQL where the duplication is mostly between rows and not in a single row?

Comment: Not if you want to query the table again. But for storage, sure, you can usually just bzip either a dump or the data files (importing InnoDB .ibd files in `MySQL` is kinda tricky though, a lot of work). What are you storing, the _new_ data or incremental _diffs_ of the data?

Comment: We store a complete copy of the old data, not a diff.

Comment: Well, there's a lot to gain there... it is of course more resource-intensive to get the data at a certain point back, but usually these kinds of audit tables are used so little the storage advantages outweigh these. If there's constant heavy 'auditing', then it would be less attractive. You could also devise a schema that at most N incremental diffs are used, after which you a full copy of the intermediate data again, so you lose some extra storage, but prevent long rebuilding of specific data.

Comment: @Wrikken: Another way of expressing the same theme would be to have periodic savepoints, and store diffs relative to those.

Comment: BTW: that a table can't be compressed, does not mean you can't get the table on a compressed filesystem... but it's performance wouid probably be quite horrible.

Comment: @eggyal: yes, periodic savepoints, that was the term I was looking for! Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation it seems like the best bet would be to put the historical audited data into a compressed, read only table and merge that with a new table that can accept new content. It would be a manual process of moving old data into compressed tables, but it would give us compression across all rows.